# GCSToGoogleDriveOperator destination_object configuration not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am using the AirFlow **GCSToGoogleDriveOperator** operator to copy a file from a GCS bucket to a specific Google Drive location.

When configuring the **destination_object** parameter, I'm unsure as to how to point this to a specified Drive location.

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B3Rc.png)

I get the following messages when executing the code:

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H0il.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the `destination_object`, you should put the path directly without the gdrive url, [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/gcs_to_gdrive.html#copy-single-files) is an example.